# Javascript: slicing off end of string

Tags: javascript, slice

Let's say I have the following strings:

```
x = 'Johnny_button'
y = 'Rebecca_button'
z = 'Alex_button'
```

I just want the word before '_button' (aka the name). How can I slice off that last part using javascript? The .slice() method doesn't seem to work as I would expect:

```
x.slice(-1, -7)
# ""
y.slice(-1, -7)
# ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `0` as the first argument, inside the `slice()` function.

```js
var x = 'Johnny_button',
    y = 'Rebecca_button',
    z = 'Alex_button';
    
    console.log(x.slice(0, -7));
    console.log(y.slice(0, -7));
    console.log(z.slice(0, -7));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/_.*$/`

```
var res = str.replace(/_.*$/g, "")
```

or `.indexOf()` with `.slice()`

```
var res = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("_"))
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It looks like it solves the problem more effectively than `slice()`.

Comment: or, for this specific case he can do `x.slice(0, x.length-7)`

Comment: @Bajal `"_button"` could be placeholder; value following "name" could be `"_button123"`?

Comment: right, that's why I said for this specific case of `_button`. He was doing "-7" anyway in code. Your solution is good as it is more generic

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir _"Apparently not as OP is already usung `slice` with `-7`"_ ? Not gathering what you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775960/javascript-slicing-off-end-of-string#comment72667163_42775978

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir How does that help future viewers of Question which may have similar inquiry? Current requirement is get text before `"_"` character. Zero or any number of characters could be included within string following delimiter `"_"` . `javascript` approaches at Answer return expected result for any characters following `"_"` are not exclusive to `"button"` word following delimiter `"_"`.

Comment: I'm just pointing out what OP is trying to achieve! Plus if `str` is `john_doe_button` I think the output should be `john_doe` not `john`!

Comment: _"I think the output should be `john_doe` not `john`! "_ Why do you think that? In which case `.lastIndexOf()` can be substituted for `.indexOf()`, instead of counting static characters.

Comment: I think it's obvious! Anyway I'm not trying to be critical or anything! Peace :)!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Of course you are being critical. Critical with purpose is helpful. Critical because of what you "think", emotional response, or sheer anethema, where `javascript` approaches at Answer return expected result is being critical without meaningful purpose. Whether you post that you "trying" to do something or "not trying" do something is not relevant. You have already done so.

Comment: Now you're being critical. P E A C E and O U T!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, am critical, here; of everything, not only "downvote" for no meaningful reason, whomever they are or "think" they are; or comments stating what the user is "not trying" to do, while doing just that. Though did not attempt to persuade or state that am not, or was not critical, of everything. There is a difference.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir If you have understanding of PEACE you are, or should be, well aware that "not trying to" is not escaped by the one whom sees all.

Comment: First of all, I didn't downvote you (I'll prove it if you want)! And this is got very intense. All I attempted to do is point out that OP is already using `slice`.

Comment: The "downvote" is irrelevant without a stated meaningful description as to why and how Answer can be improved. That is an emotional "downvote", devoid of meaning or purpose, and dismissed as such. Yes, there is a `.slice()` approach at Answer. Have no issues with "intense", here; whatever the outcome may be. You begot this exchange. Not sure what you expected result of initial comment to be?

Comment: I'm really speechless right now, the last thing I've ever thought of is to have a conversation such as this where it started by something simple as a _Apparently not as OP is already usung `slice` with `-7`_ to _is not escaped by the one whom sees all_ (that was a wow moment). Anyway I'm sorry if I made you uncomfortable by my **"criticism"**, I really am. I'll upvote so you'll know that I'm not the downvoter (it's hard to believe a suspect, believe me, I know, I tried to suggest on meta that they make the downvoter not anonimous but failed). Sorry, sorry sorry!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir You are mistaking this user for another two-legged. Do not have concern over "downvote", other than it is useless without accompanying description of what is lacking at Answer and what can be improved, or if incapable of being improved, will delete Answer if does not add positives. Invite criticism, here; to improve approaches to current and future endeavors. "sorry" is absolutely meaningless to this user. Once the act is done, there is no undoing the act. Conduct is the only activity that can be measured, not an individuals' state of mind nor emotional responses.

Comment: Well let's put an end to this conversation as I've grown weary of it. The world record's been broken 20 comments ago!

Answer (score 1):

Use `0` instead of `-1` and it will work. You want to start the selected substring at index 0 (the begin of the input), not right before the last character.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, You can try 'split' method. It will return an array like below:

```js
var a = 'Johnny_button'.split('_');
var name = a[0];
console.log(name);
```

[MDN split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *match*, though I think guest271314's answer is better:

```js
['Johnny_button','noUnderscore','_nothingBefore'].forEach(
  function (s) {
    console.log( s + ' => ' + (s.match(/^[^_]*/) || [])[0] );
  });
```